# Trouble positioning specific elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to edit the margins/border/padding of the main posts, without it affecting my sidebar. Instead of doing that, everything on the webpage is affected. Perhaps it's a problem with my "div" elements? I'm sure I'm just overlooking something but I've spent so much time looking at this code I can't begin to see it clearly. Anyone have some help? Thanks in advance. It's for a Tumblr btw, but I doubt that affects this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>


<head>
<title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
    {block:Description}
        <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
    {/block:Description}

    <!-- DEFAULT COLORS -->
    <meta name="color:Background" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="color:Center Background" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="color:Post Background" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="color:Accent" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="color:Links" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="color:Used Links" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="color:Body Text" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="color:Title Text" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="font:Body" content="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Monospace" 
/>
    <meta name="font:Title" content="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,           
Monospace"> 








</head>

<style type="text/css">
{CustomCSS}

#profile img {
position:fixed, absolute;

margin-bottom:-16%;
}

#Sidebar {
background-color:{color:Accent};
position:fixed;
text-align: left;
font-family:{font:Title};
color:{color:Title Text};
float:left;

width:12%;
height:auto;

margin-top:2%;
margin-bottom:1%;
margin-left:6%;
margin-right:1%;

border-top:1%;
border-bottom:1%;
border-left:2%;
border-right:1%;

padding-top:2%;
padding-bottom:1%;
padding-left:2%;
padding-right:1%;  
}

.try {
font-family:{font:Body};
margin-top:;
margin-bottom:3%;
margin-left:24%;
margin-right:1%;}


#permalink {
width:auto;
height:auto;

margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-left:27%;
margin-right:1%;
}

#footer {
font-family:{font:Body};
text-align:center;

width:21%;
height:auto;

margin-top:1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:2%;

border-top:1%;
border-bottom:1%;
border-left:2%;
border-right:2%;

padding-top:1%;
padding-bottom:1%;
padding-left:2%;
padding-right:2%; 

}
</style>
<div id="Wrap">
<body bgcolor="{color:Background}" link="{color:Links}" vlink="{color:Used     
Links}">



<div id="Sidebar">  

<div id="profile"><img src="{PortraitURL-96}"/></div> 
<h2 id="Title"><a href="{BlogURL}">{Title}</a></h2>
<p id="Description">
{block:Description}{Description}
{/block:Description}
</p>


{block:HasPages}
{block:Pages}

<p id="About"><a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></p>
{/block:Pages}
{/block:HasPages}



{block:AskEnabled}
<p id="asks"><a href="/ask">{AskLabel}</a></p>
{/block:AskEnabled}
</div> <!--Sidebar-->
<div id="postwrap"> 
<ol id="posts">





{block:Posts} 

<div class="try">


{block:Text}


<div id="text">
{block:Title}
<h4><a href="{Permalink}" a>{Title}</a></h4>{/block:Title}
{Body}

</div> <!--text-->
{/block:Text}

</div> <!--try-->


<div class="try">

{block:Photo}
 <div id="photo">


<img src="{PhotoURL-400}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
{block:Caption}
 <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
 {/block:Caption}


 {NoteCountWithLabel} 
 </div> <!--try-->
 {/block:Photo}

 </div> <!--photo-->



 <div class="try">

 {block:Panorama}
 <div id="panorama">
 {LinkOpenTag}
  <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">
 {LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}
 <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
 {/block:Caption}

{NoteCountWithLabel}
</div> <!--panorama-->
{/block:Panorama}

</div> <!--try-->


<div class="try">

{block:Photoset}
<div id="photoset">
{Photoset-500}{block:Caption}
   <div class="caption">{Caption}</div> <!--caption-->
 {/block:Caption}
{NoteCountWithLabel}
 </div> <!--photoset-->
 {/block:Photoset}

 </div> <!--try-->


 <div class="try">

{block:Quote}
<div id="Quote">
"{Quote}"

{block:Source}
  <div class="source">{Source}</div>
  {/block:Source}
 {NoteCountWithLabel} 
 </div> <!--quote-->
{/block:Quote}

</div> <!--try-->

<div class="try">

{block:Link}
<div id="link">
 <a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>
 {block:Description}
   <div class="description">{Description}</div>
   {/block:Description}
{NoteCountWithLabel}   
</div> <!--link-->
{/block:Link}

</div> <!--try-->


<div class="try">

{block:Chat}
<div id="chat">

                    {block:Title}
                        <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                    {/block:Title}

                    <ul class="chat">
                        {block:Lines}
                            <li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
                                {block:Label}<strong>
                                    <span class="label">{Label}</strong>   
 </span>
                                {/block:Label}{Line}
                            </li>
                        {/block:Lines}
                    </ul>
            {NoteCountWithLabel}
            </div> <!--chat-->
            {/block:Chat}

            </div> <!--try-->



<div class="try">

{block:Video}
    <div id="video">
                <li class="post video">
                    {Video-500}{block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
                {NoteCountWithLabel}
            </div> <!--video-->
            {/block:Video}
            </div> <!--try-->


            <div class="try">

            {block:Audio}
            <div id="Audio">
                <li class="post audio">
                    {AudioEmbed}{block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
                <link rel="notes" href="{URL}/>{NoteCountWithLabel}
                </div> <!--audio-->
            {/block:Audio}

            </div> <!--try--> 
          <div id="permalink">
 <a href="{Permalink}">
 {block:Date}{lang:Posted TimeAgo}{/block:Date}
 {block:NoteCount} with {NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
 </a>
 </div>
 {block:PostNotes}
 <div id="notecontainer">{PostNotes}</div>
 {/block:PostNotes}

            {/block:Posts}

            </div> <!--Post Wrap-->
            </div> <!--Likes and Reblogs-->

            </ol>

 <div class="try">
 <div id="footer">
        {block:PreviousPage}
            <a href="{PreviousPage}">&#171; Previous</a>
        {/block:PreviousPage}{block:NextPage}
            <a href="{NextPage}">Next &#187;</a>
        {/block:NextPage}


        <a href="/archive">Archive</a>
 </div>
 </p>

 </div> <!--wrap-->
 </div> <!--Footer-->



 </body>

 </HTML>
```

Sorry if my code is awful, I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

Positioning in CSS is hard at first, largely because it doesn't throw errors as such - it just doesn't work. Firstly think about exactly what you want to achieve - you have added position fixed to your sidebar, but I suspect this is more out of frustration and trying to make it work than actually wanting it to be position fixed, as the content lower down the page is now out of sight.

Having added this, it makes it very hard to see what is going wrong elsewhere.

A couple of general pointers which will make your life easier:

1. Try to only style using classes as hooks. So instead of #sidebar use .sidebar ( instead of ) This will create a level playing field - id's are much, much more specific than classes and in general you always want to keep your specificity as low as possible. See more here: http://css-tricks.com/strategies-keeping-css-specificity-low/
2. Look up CSS properties when you first use them - great resource here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/

More specifically:

You want to create a sidebar of 12% width, with a content area taking up the rest of the space and then style elements within it. So your wrappers should be something like:

```
<body>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div> <!-- This currently in your .try div -->
</body>
```

Now add the following styles:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 12%; /* This will set the width of the sidebar */
    padding: 0 20px; /* This will give you padding left and right*/
    float: left; /* This will move it to the left of the page */
}
.content {
    width: 88%;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left; /* This will stack the content div against the sidebar div */
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

The border box bit: This will reset your box sizing to border box, this will keep your widths as expected because it will calculate the padding as part of the width rather than adding it to the width which gets very confusing. See more here: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Demo here: http://codepen.io/simoncmason/pen/QwmLxV

I hope this gets your rolling.